# Antd EditableProTable valueNum is column based how to set different value in each row

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Antd EditableProTable where i am trying to create select box and i am setting options value in valueEnum but for second row for same column my valueEnum is different but how to set that?
In normal antd table there is concept of datasource but here that takes just the data which have to be shown on first time render but not the select options you have to define it in column levels only but then the problem is it render the same in each row.

How to provide different select box data for each row.Any help would be great.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzSFz.png)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have not tried, but as API in `antd` docs, the render can do this work. Let's try to config the select options of the `<Select>` according to the record of that row. For example, you pass two additional cols (but hide them by `hideInTable` prop) that have two options data, then when render the `<Select>` you get the data from them.

Good luck!

Comment: even though if i able to achive it by using render , i wont be able to get value under editable property of it i mean inside this
`even though if i able to achive it by using render , i wont be able to get value under editable property of it i mean inside this
editable = {{
    type: 'multiple',
        editableKeys,
        onValuesChange: (record, recordList) => {
            console.log(record);
        }
        }}`

Comment: i am unable to get that drop down value which i rendered custom. rest all column values are present in record. how to get that custom render drop down value?

Comment: In your case, let's `config select options of each due to other value in the current row`. For example, each record contains Name, Role and a dropdown to select his/her Leader, the select options must depend on the role. You just need to call API for that specific dropdown options base on the role value when render the dropdown

{
      title: 'leader',
      valueType: 'option',
      width: 250,
      render: (record) => {
        // handle API to get options (use record.role)
  
        return <Dropdown options={options} />
      },
    },

Comment: I have used rowselection prop also in editable table. when i am unchecking a row i want to reset all 3 drop down which are present in that row. so far i tried reseting their value to null but i am having hard time setting their values because if i use state it is affecting chosen value. I am unable to set ref value for select field in antd. if you have any working example to set select box option programatically through ref that will be great.I can't go thorugh form.resetfield() route because it is not a form i am getting these value from onchange.